# Help Identifying/Decoding Ceramic Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, identification, emc, ceramic

I am having a difficult time identifying a high voltage, ceramic capacitor that I need to replace. I've tried at length to research this myself to no avail. I am hoping that someone out there can help me with this. Apart from the first line on the capacitor which I am reading as 220pF ±10%, I don't know how to interpret the rest. I cannot find a meaning for the symbol at the bottom that is a half circle with a bowtie in the middle of it and what does the tilde mean in this context? Cannot determine the voltage etc Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 6):

Its a murata cap, made in Thailand. Here is a link to [the PDF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi-sMnQnp3eAhVIDq0KHRUTCXoQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsearch.murata.co.jp%2FCeramy%2Fimage%2Fimg%2FA01X%2FG101%2FENG%2FDE1_KX_N01F_E.pdf&psig=AOvVaw3TpfHgkHzS6-6RlSW8Tbhd&ust=1540407332661014)

Has a value of 220pf
Probably one of these [at digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/capacitors/ceramic-capacitors/60?k=murata%20250%20capacitor&k=&pkeyword=murata%20250%20capacitor&pv2049=u2200pF&sf=0&FV=ffe0003c%2Cffec1679&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=500)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

See [this document](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/281/c85e-522724.pdf)

Page 38:

- 221K: Nominal capacitance: 221, K: Capacitance tolerance, K: +/- 10%
- KX: Type designation KX,
- X1Y1:   See Features, item 8:

  - Rated Voltage: X1: AC440V(r.m.s.), Y1: AC250V(r.m.s.) or
  - X1: AC440V(r.m.s.), Y1: AC300V (r.m.s.)
- 22: Manufactured date class
- M15: Company Name Code: M15: Made in Thailand

Answer (score 2):

This is marked '221K' which commonly means 220 pF,10% tolerance,
in an EIA standard marking.   The '250~' indicates
that it is rated for 250VAC.   Beyond that, the 'X1Y1' string 
probably indicates that this component is safety-rated for direct
line connection (and would be considered a safety-critical component).

The color and the lower string probably indicate the manufacturer and
possibly even the factory of origin.

This reference may help with similar questions: [wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Read-a-Capacitor)